# Where can I find a dataset of academic conferences?

Tags: data-request, research

I'm looking for a dataset of academic conferences containing, for each of their editions, as many following field as possible:

- impact factor (+ optionally any other qualitative assessments)
- field (optionally subfield + keywords related to it)
- number of papers/posters/demo submitted and accepted
- location
- date
- number of attendees
- whether it was recorded (audio/video)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that you scrape the data on [SSRN](http://www.ssrn.com/) by looking by field/location/date.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for a specific field, or just ALL academic conferences?

It may be good to start to pick one field (i.e. [computer science](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/db/conf/indexa.html)) which will provide more data but for fewer conferences. Another option is [SSRN](http://www.ssrn.com/en/), like @Noobie mentioned.

If you want ALL conferences, then you may have to go with a third-party site and then do some [scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping). In the past I've scraped [allconferences.com](http://www.allconferences.com/), which is useful because each event has a useful URL ([example](http://www.allconferences.com/c/hr-in-hospitality-conference-2014-april-28)). This would meet some of your criterea (field, location, date) but miss others (impact factor, number of papers, number of attendees). Also, that site is far from complete, so you rely on their collection algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, I'm mostly looking for computer science, but ideally all fields.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding computer science, the [Conference Acceptance Ratio Statistics](http://www.adaptivebox.net/CILib/CICON_stat.html) page contains many conferences onComputational Intelligence & Related, and specify the number of papers/posters/demo submitted and accepted, date and 
number of attendees. It also has pointers (most are dead links now...) to similar databases for [Networking](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~almeroth/conf/stats/), [Software Engineering](http://www.csc.ncsu.edu/faculty/xie/seconferences.htm), [Database](http://wwwhome.cs.utwente.nl/~apers/rates.html), [Graphics/Interaction/Vision](http://vrlab.epfl.ch/~ulicny/statistics/), [Hardware and Architecture](http://oergin.etu.edu.tr/ingilizce/acceptance_rates.html).